# Using ImpersonatedCredentials with python api for GCP PubSub SubscriberClient

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-authentication, google-api-python-client

I'm attempting to create a `SubscriberClient` using `ImpersontatedCredentials` (impersonating a service account) using the python pubsub API, and then creating some subscriptions with that client. I'm attempting to try to run this code locally (though eventually it will get deployed as a cloud function)

In doing so, I get this error:

> filter: "attributes.provider_id = "integration_test_create_delete_provider_id_123""
> , metadata=[('x-goog-request-params', 'name=projects/my-project/subscriptions/integration_test_create_delete_provider_id_123'), ('x-goog-api-client', 'gl-python/3.8.6 grpc/1.39.0 gax/1.31.1 gccl/2.7.0')]), last exception: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('Unable to acquire impersonated credentials: No access token or invalid expiration in response.', '{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 400,\n    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",\n    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"\n  }\n}\n')

My code to create the impersonated credentials looks like this:

```
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

target_scopes = [
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub",
]
target_principal = ("target-svc-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",)

def _get_impersonated_pubsub_client():
    return pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient(credentials=_get_impersonated_creds())


def _get_impersonated_creds():
    default_creds, _ = google.auth.default()
    impersonated_creds = impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
        source_credentials=default_creds,
        target_principal=target_principal,
        target_scopes=target_scopes,
    )
    return impersonated_creds
```

From there, I call `create_subscription(request=my_request)` on the client I get from calling `_get_impersonated_pubsub_client()`, and after about a minute I see the above error.

My request object looks like this:

```
{
        "name": "projects/my-project/subscriptions/integration_test_create_delete_provider_id_123",
        "topic": "projects/my-project/topics/my-topic-dev-us-west1",
}
```

If I make the same call *without* impersonation or specifying credentials in the `SubscriberClient` constructor, everything works great.

My immediate first thought was it was a permission error, but I double checked that my source account has the `ServiceAccountTokenCreator` role.

Additionally, I tried to run an equivalent command with the GCloud CLI (including the impersonation) like this:

`gcloud pubsub subscriptions create my_subscription_name --topic=projects/my-project/topics/my-topic-dev-us-west1 --impersonate-service-account target-svc-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

This works exactly as expected -- which leads me to believe the permissions in GCP are set up correctly.

Does the `SubscriberClient` not work with `ImpersonatedCredentials`, or is there some coercion I could do to make the auth work?

I also made sure to run `gcloud config unset auth/impersonate_service_account` and then `gcloud auth application-default login` to ensure my local credentials were in a good state.

Relevant dependencies:

```
google-api-core[grpc]==1.31.1; platform_python_implementation != 'PyPy'
google-api-python-client==2.15.0; python_version >= '3.6'
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth==1.34.0
google-cloud-core==2.0.0b1; python_version >= '3.6'
google-cloud-firestore==2.2.0; platform_python_implementation != 'PyPy'
google-cloud-pubsub==2.7.0
google-cloud-storage==1.41.1; python_version >= '2.7' and python_version not in '3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5'
google-crc32c==1.1.2; python_version >= '3.6'
google-resumable-media==2.0.0b1; python_version >= '3.6'
googleapis-common-protos[grpc]==1.53.0; python_version >= '3.6'
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpcio==1.39.0
httplib2==0.19.1
```

Comment: I'm able to use `ImpersonatedCredentials` with the Pub/Sub `SubscriberClient` successfully. Could you try upgrading your dependencies to their latest versions? `pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib google-cloud-pubsub`

Comment: @Lauren I gave that a shot but my results are the same.  I also added the relevant sections of my requirements.txt file into the original question for reference.  If it matters I'm using pipenv to manage my dependencies, so this is a generated requirements.txt file, rather than a hand made one.

Comment: @Lauren are you using `google.auth.default()` to create the source credentials for your impersonated credentials? I'm wondering if perhaps I should not be doing that.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO your Python code appears correct.

Complete the following steps:

1. List the services that are enabled:

**gcloud services list --enabled**

2. Verify that **iamcredentials.googleapis.com** is enabled. To enable:

**gcloud services enable iamcredentials.googleapis.com**

3. Verify that **cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com** is enabled. To enable:

**gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com**

4. Verify that the Compute Engine default service account has the role **roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator** or better.

The required permission are:

- **iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken**
- **iam.serviceAccounts.getOpenIdToken** (this permission is required to fetch identity tokens).

  gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROECT_ID] 
  --member "serviceAccount:[GCE_DEFAULT_SA_FULL_EMAIL]" 
  --role "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"

5. Verify that the Compute Engine default service account has the role **roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer** or better.

   gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROECT_ID] 
   --member "serviceAccount:[GCE_DEFAULT_SA_FULL_EMAIL]" 
   --role "roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer"

**If any of the previous are not enabled/granted, token issuance will fail.**

Note: If you only want the Compute Engine service account to be able to impersonate one service account, change step 4 to grant the role on the service account instead of the project:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding [SA_FULL_EMAIL] \
--member serviceAccount:[GCE_DEFAULT_SA_FULL_EMAIL] \
--role roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
```

Comment: I'm running through the checklist now -- just to confirm, for the required permissions (getAccessToken, getOpenIdToken) what accounts should have those permissions? My default credential account, or the target account?

Comment: @istrupin The account that is impersonating another identity. In my answer **GCE_DEFAULT_SA_FULL_EMAIL** is the account that wants to impersonate **SA_FULL_EMAIL**.

Comment: @istrupin Note: I am assuming that you are running on Google Compute Engine. Your code is using the ADC (Application Default Credentials) which gets a token from the Metadata server. If you are testing on your desktop, the ADC default credentials are setup using **gcloud auth application-default login**. Everything stays the same. Just make sure you get the identies (email) correct.

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm running in a cloud function when I'm deployed.  Locally, yeah I expected it to work the same way that my CLI works as far as credentials, and my CLI command does work with the --impersonate flag, so I expect that this means the permissions are correct.  Are the permissions going to be different for CLI vs Python API?

Comment: @istrupin - The required permissions/roles/services are the same. As far as ADC goes, Cloud Functions has similar features to Google Compute Engine just fewer metadata keys.

Comment: Thanks @John Hanley So I've gone through this checklist a number of times, but am still not having much luck.  When the above python locally, I get the aforementioned error.  When running the CLI locally with impersonation, everything works, so perhaps the issue is with the way I'm getting credentials in python?