# GitHub Action to GCP - Unable to acquire impersonated credentials: No access token or invalid expiration in response

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I am trying to set up a deployment pipeline from GitHub action to GAE.

I start off by following this doc https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth#setup,
using the **Setting up Workload Identity Federation** method.

It looks like everything seems to be working smoothly until the part where I either use `gcloud app deploy` or `gcloud services list --enabled` or any cmd needing authentication (In the "Build" step).

**.github\workflows\app-engine.yml**

```
name: Build using Cloud Build

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main

env:
  PROJECT_ID: testinfra3
  SERVICE_NAME: default

jobs:
  setup-build-deploy:
    name: Setup, Build, and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: 'read'
      id-token: 'write'
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - id: 'auth'
      name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0'
      with:
        workload_identity_provider: 'projects/123456789/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/my-pool/providers/my-provider' 
        service_account: 'my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'
    - name: 'Set up Cloud SDK'
      uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v0
    - name: 'Build'
      run: |-
        gcloud app deploy
```

**In the GitHub action deployment logs**

[image]

[image]

[image]

I came across this solution [Using ImpersonatedCredentials with python api for GCP PubSub SubscriberClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68627952/using-impersonatedcredentials-with-python-api-for-gcp-pubsub-subscriberclient) where he explained that some services and roles need to be bound and enabled. I tried it but still getting the same deployment error.

Here is a list of services enabled

[image]

**Progress update 1**

I restarted the whole process again and took @Juan and @John Hanley advice.
I found out that one of the mistake that i did was at step 8 the repo naming part instead of including the full path like `username/repo_name` i only use `repo_name`.

Now i have a new error message:

[image]

I guess it is due to permission issue to i try to set the service account to owner level but it is still not working!

[image]

**Progress update 2**

The screenshot above was a image from permission page under service `my-github@testinfra6.iam.gserviceaccount.com` that was why i was still getting the same error. What i had to do is add it from page `IAM - Admin -> IAM -> Add`, Ok adding permission works from there

Comment: 1) Edit your question and list the services that you enabled such as STS (security token service). 2) Is your Google Cloud Project standalone or part of an Organization? 3) which commands did you run to set up the pool and provider?

Comment: To keep assisting you, please provide me with the information that John asked from you. It's necessary to check all parameters and information.

Comment: 1- Ive listed the services that is enabled... please check the edit screen shot. 2- My google project is part of an Organization. 3 - like i mentioned i follow the instruction in this doc https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth#setup @JohnHanley

Comment: Questions and answers should be self-contained if possible. Links are deleted, modified, etc which could render your question useless in the future. We do not know if you followed those steps correctly. If you do not remember those steps then I recommend that you delete the pool and provider and start over.

Comment: I willl give that a try

Comment: @JohnHanley I restarted the whole process again and found out that i made a mistake on step 8. Now i am trying to figure out why setting up my service account as an owner still not working, ive editted the question.

Comment: Ok i think i understood the permission page incorrect, as i have to add the roles to IAM - Admin -> IAM -> Add instead of adding it through specific service account

Answer (score 6):

For anyone trying to resolve this issue, make sure you have the `IAM Service Account Credentials API` API enabled, [iamcredentials.googleapis.com](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/reference/credentials/rest) in your GCP project first, which then enables the creation of short-lived tokens for service account impersonations.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Thank you for flagging this up!

Answer (score 5):

I run into the same error yesterday. I made a typo in the step 8 of `google-github-actions` configuration and the new permission of the service account was wrong.

You can check it through the IAM page -> Service Accounts -> Permissions (tab).

Comment: I made a mistake on step 8 but is not due to typo but repo naming was incorrect format but i am still trying to figure out why i am still getting permission error @Juan