# github actions to GCP OIDC error: 403 'Unable to acquire impersonated credentials' [principalSet mismatch with the Subject claim]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions

I have been looking at similar issues here through closed issues on https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth but I'm still struggling for a week to get my github repo to obtain a gcp access token from it's subject claim, checked OIDC related errors but nothing comes close.

- Yes I checked similar questions >> [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71559312/14744336)  and no, the fix doesn't apply to my case

All I'm trying to mapp is:

```
${MYREPO}:environment:my-env
```

which I confirmed the structure from the official [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/security-hardening-your-deployments/about-security-hardening-with-openid-connect#understanding-the-oidc-token)

```
"sub": "repo:octo-org/octo-repo:environment:prod"
```

but  nothing worked so far .

everything seems to be working smoothly until the part where gcloud services list command is ran

````
name: 'Terraform_gcp_vpc'

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "git_actions" ]
    paths:
...
jobs:
  
  terraform_setup:
    name: 'Terraform Init-Validate'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: gcp-labs
 runner 
    defaults:
     run:
       shell: bash
       working-directory: ${{ env.STACK_DIR }}

    steps:
# Checkout the repository to the GitHub Actions runner
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
 #  Authenticate with GCP  using OIDC Workload Federated Identiry 
    - name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
      id: auth
      uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
      with:
        workload_identity_provider: ${{ secrets.WORKLOAD_ID_PROVIDER }} 
        service_account: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
        
  # Install gcloud, `setup-gcloud` automatically picks up authentication from `auth`.
    - name: 'Set up Cloud SDK'
      uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1'   
    - id: 'gcloud'
      name: 'gcloud'
      run: gcloud services list
    ```
````

[image]

```
Error: (gcloud.services.list) There was a problem refreshing your current auth tokens: 'Unable to acquire impersonated credentials'
 {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission \'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken\' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    "details":
   [
      {
      "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",        
      "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
      "metadata": {
      "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
      }
    }
   ]
  }
 }
```

## Attribute-Mapping

[image]

## PrincipalSet

```
principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/attribute.repository/${REPO}:environment:gcp-labs"
```

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71559312/github-action-to-gcp-unable-to-acquire-impersonated-credentials-no-access-tok

Comment: You have a permission problem: `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken`. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-permissions That means you did not set up Workload Identity Federation correctly.

Comment: Look at this section: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-other-providers#allow_the_external_workload_to_impersonate_the_service_account

Comment: @john-hanley I did , I run through all the doc and did it by the books , before opening the OP .  didn't put everything above but give this gist a look  gist if it can help: https://gist.github.com/brokedba/b473ce5812f582e164da55d787c3d588

Comment: The problem is very simple, the identity does not have the permission  `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken`, add an IAM role with that permission `roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser`. If that does not make sense, study the permissions section on WIF and documentation on Service Account impersonation.

Comment: If you read step 4 in the gist I shared you'll see that it was done already.
don't think it's a permission issue , it's maybe the attribute-mapping that is not matching with principalset claim of the binding wich represents my github tokenID.

to put the whole question simply: 
 
- What would be the attribute mapping and Principalset matching below subnet claim? 
  => `repo:${MYREPO}:environment:myenv` 

1. --attribute-mapping="?? 
2. --member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/attribute.?/?"

Comment: I see the steps you documented, but that does not mean you did it correctly or that you did not notice a subtle warning message. When this has happened to me, I just delete everything and start over. It takes less time than debugging mistakes.

Comment: agree on the WIF side , but only for the principalset and the mapping which I did few times using the GUI , but all combinations seem to fail. It doesn't make sense to do that on the git workflow as code is clean so far.

I think GCP or github could do a little more effort into documenting examples that are more specific than basic attribute.actor+attribute.repository  subject claim.

Comment: I have deployed WIF with GitHub, Azure, and AWS dozens of times. It does work which means you did something wrong. Persistence is a great developer quality. Stubbornness is not. Start over and consider it practice.

Comment: I hear you , but I did deploy WIF on Azure and AWS as well and it was very fast and intuitive . 
see AWS trsutPolicy below super clear and simple, GCP oidc experience is nothing like the other 2: 
```
            "Condition": {
              "StringEquals": {
                "token.actions.githubusercontent.com:sub":[
                    "repo:brokedba/terraform-examples:ref:push",
                    "repo:brokedba/terraform-examples:ref:refs/heads/git_actions",
                    "repo:brokedba/terraform-examples:environment:aws-labs"
                ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The problem was due to the fact that I tried to use a principalset to declare the google subject claim.
- You can not use subject claim inside a **Principalset** , the only permitted pattern in the Principalset is known/custom attributes.
  [image]
- If you want to use a subject you need to switch to **Principals** in your SA policy binding statement.

*See detailed examples below**

## Using attributes (Principalset)

- I found a solution to get my repo authenticated using a provider custom attribute. I used the below custom attribute and assertion concatenation (repo+environment)
  WIF provider mapping.
  I called the attribute full.

```
gcloud iam workload-identity-pools providers create-oidc 
gitaction-oidc-provider" \
--project="${PROJECT_ID}" --location="global" --workload-identity-pool="github-pool" \
 --display-name="gitactions-oidc-provider" --attribute-mapping="google.subject=assertion.sub, \ 
 attribute.full=assertion.repository+assertion.environment \
 --issuer-uri="https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com
```

- SA iam policy binding : The claim concatenation paterne implies there is no delimiter between repo and environment

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding "$SA" --project="${PROJECT_ID}" \
--role="roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser" \ 
--member="principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/${WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_POOL_ID}/attribute.full/${REPO}gcp-labs
```

This worked right away.

## Using subject claim (Principal)

when I used the GitHub Actions OIDC debugger,This is what my debugger replied with :

```
{
  "actor": "brokedba",
  "aud": "https://github.com/brokedba",
  "environment": "gcp-labs",
  "event_name": "push",
   "iss": "https://token.actions.githubusercontent.com",
 "job_workflow_ref": "brokedba/terraform-examples/.github/workflows/terraform_gcp-labs_vpc.yml@refs/heads/git_actions",
  "ref": "refs/heads/git_actions",
  "ref_type": "branch",
  "repository": "brokedba/terraform-examples",
  "repository_owner": "brokedba",
...
 "sub": "repo:brokedba/terraform-examples:environment:gcp-labs",  <<--- subject
 "workflow": "Terraform_gcp_vpc",
 "workflow_ref": "brokedba/terraform-examples/.github/workflows/terraform_gcp-labs_vpc.yml@refs/heads/git_actions",
  }
```

This is the right member expression   :

```
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding "$SA" --project="${PROJECT_ID}" \
--role="roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser" \ 
principal://iam.googleapis.com/projects/xx/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/mypool/subject/repo:brokedba/terraform-examples:environment:gcp-labs
```

---

.

## Closing remark

I dug through GCP docs but haven't found an article/doc explaining clear differences between Principal VS PrincipalSet . But,
here is a little summary for those who might end up in a similar spot.

**1. Principals**

- The principal configuration allows you to specify a single identity that is allowed to impersonate a service account.
- A regular principal is the basic way of identifying an incoming request to WIF and essentially just uses the subject.
- This is the default subject for an OIDC token issued in GitHub Actions.
- Therefore in github actions the principal configuration is typically sufficient for most common cases (single identity representing the GitHub Actions environment).
- example:

```
"principal://iam.googleapis.com/projects/${PROJECT_NUMBER}/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/subject/repo:${REPO}:ref:refs/heads/mybranch"
```

**2. Principalsets**

- PrincipalSet configuration would involve specifying a group of principals that are allowed to impersonate the service account.
- The main difference to a regular principal is that they don’t just use the subject from the request, but instead use any of the custom attributes that have been mapped from the JWT claims in the provider.
- example:|

```
"principalSet://iam.googleapis.com/projects/PROJECT_NUMBER/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/attribute.repository/${REPO}"
```

- Note that the URI scheme is now principalSet instead of principal
- with these attribute you can set up some very fine grained controls to allow access to specific service accounts from specific events on specific repositories.

Comment: Your answer looks interesting. Can you write a single sentence or two at the bugging showing the exact changes necessary to solve your problem? how the original command and/or setting and the required change. Explaining the details is nice, but the solution should be clearly stated at the beginning. I understand WIF well and I would have to analyze your answer to find the problem and solution. Most will not spend the time.

Comment: Done. Always fun to answer one's question.